# LINQ: Field is not a reference field

Tags: linq, data-structures, where-clause, iqueryable

I've got a list of IQueryable. I'm trying to split this list into an array of IQueryable matching on a certain field (say fieldnum) in the first list...

for example, if fieldnum == 1, it should go into array[1]. I'm using Where() to filter based on this field, it looks something like this:

```
var allItems = FillListofMyObjects();        
var Filtered = new List<IQueryable<myObject>(MAX+1);

for (var i = 1; i <= MAX; i++)
{
        var sublist = allItems.Where(e => e.fieldnum == i);
        if (sublist.Count() == 0) continue;

        Filtered[i] = sublist;
}
```

however, I'm getting the error **Field "t1.fieldnum" is not a reference field** on the if line. stepping through the debugger shows the error actually occurs on the line before (the Where() method) but either way, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I'm farily new to LINQ so if I'm doing this all wrong please let me know, thanks!

Comment: is allItems null when you get that error?

Comment: no it is populated with an IQueryable of type MyObject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just use [ToLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx)?

```
var allItemsPerFieldNum = allItems.ToLookup(e => e.fieldnum);
```

Do you need to reevaluate the expression every time you get the values?

Comment: interesting! this is the first i've heard of the ToLookup method, I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: wow that worked PERFECTLY! thanks, not sure what the original error was but this completely does the job with no issues, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a dictionary?

```
var dictionary = allItems.ToDictionar(y => y.fieldnum);
```

Comment: since each fieldnum can have more than one object, the ToLookup is the better data structure, but thanks!